# vb.net password validation using regular expressions

Tags: vb.net

How does one call a function to validate a password which has been put into a textbox?

```
Function ValidatePassword(ByVal pwd As String, 
Optional ByVal minLength As Integer = 8, 
Optional ByVal numUpper As Integer = 2, 
Optional ByVal numLower As Integer = 2, 
Optional ByVal numNumbers As Integer = 2, 
Optional ByVal numSpecial As Integer = 2) As Boolean

' Replace [A-Z] with \p{Lu}, to allow for Unicode uppercase letters.
Dim upper As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[A-Z]")
Dim lower As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[a-z]")
Dim number As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[0-9]")
' Special is "none of the above".
Dim special As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9]")

' Check the length.
If Len(pwd) < minLength Then Return False
' Check for minimum number of occurrences.
If upper.Matches(pwd).Count < numUpper Then Return False
If lower.Matches(pwd).Count < numLower Then Return False
If number.Matches(pwd).Count < numNumbers Then Return False
If special.Matches(pwd).Count < numSpecial Then Return False

' Passed all checks.
Return True
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

To use this function you will need to grab the text from the password textbox and put it into the function:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim strPwd As String
    strPwd = TextboxPassword.Text 'textbox containing password
    If ValidatePassword(strPwd) = True Then
        MessageBox.Show("Password is valid!")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Password is invalid. Please try again.")
    End If
End Sub

Function ValidatePassword(ByVal pwd As String,
        Optional ByVal minLength As Integer = 8,
        Optional ByVal numUpper As Integer = 2,
        Optional ByVal numLower As Integer = 2,
        Optional ByVal numNumbers As Integer = 2,
        Optional ByVal numSpecial As Integer = 2) As Boolean

    ' Replace [A-Z] with \p{Lu}, to allow for Unicode uppercase letters.
    Dim upper As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[A-Z]")
    Dim lower As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[a-z]")
    Dim number As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[0-9]")
    ' Special is "none of the above".
    Dim special As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9]")

    ' Check the length.
    If Len(pwd) < minLength Then Return False
    ' Check for minimum number of occurrences.
    If upper.Matches(pwd).Count < numUpper Then Return False
    If lower.Matches(pwd).Count < numLower Then Return False
    If number.Matches(pwd).Count < numNumbers Then Return False
    If special.Matches(pwd).Count < numSpecial Then Return False

    ' Passed all checks.
    Return True
End Function
```

Note that the other parameters are optional.  You will only need to put the password text into the function.  When you click Button1 the code executes, eventually calls on the function ValidatePassword, and sends out a message box to tell you if the password was valid or not.